# SQL query for finding the movies that users haven't watched

Tags: sql, oracle

[Let, these are the two tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2JL4Y.jpg)

[I've used except keyword to get the desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Gmyb.jpg)

Now, my case is that there are two tables having:

1. All the user-related data is available (user_id, email, contact...) User_id is of importance for us.
2. User_id and the movie name that a particular user watches ( multiple records can be there for each user ) Basically this table is created when any user watches a movie that is available.

I don't have the list of available movies, so let us assume that all the movies have been covered by some or the other user in table 2. By using a distinct keyword will give all the movies available.

I need to get a query that gives the output like the user id and the movies that the particular user **hasn't watched**. Is there a way to get the output **without** using "PLSQL", "except", "anti join", or "exists" keyword on SQL

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    "tabl1"."type",
    "tabl2"."user_id"
FROM
    "tabl2"
RIGHT JOIN 
    "tabl1" ON "tabl1"."userid"  = "tabl2"."user_id"  
WHERE
    "tabl1"."type" NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT "type"
                           FROM "tabl1" 
                           LEFT JOIN "tabl2" ON "tabl1"."userid"  = "tabl2"."user_id"  
                           WHERE "tabl2"."user_id" IN (SELECT DISTINCT "user_id"
                                                       FROM "tabl2"))
```

I've tried using the join operation but it doesn't give any result and end up having NULL only.

I'm stuck on how to get the required output.

[Is there a way to get a similar output like this without using the functions described above.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLI7k.png)

Comment: can i suggest giving an example which has names which pertain to the question at hand, eg, "movies", "users", "movies_watched" etc etc... Otherwise people will misinterpret the question and the sample SQL you've provided

Comment: I don't understand why you dismiss certain approaches. Okay PL/SQL is a programming language and you want it done in SQL. Anti joins are a trick used on DBMS with a weak optimizer that have problems with `NOT EXISTS` and `NOT IN`. You don't want to muddle trough with it and end up with a less readable query, okay. But `EXCEPT` (or `MINUS` in Oracle) and `NOT EXISTS` are appropriate methods. Why dismiss them?

Comment: @Thorsten Kettner
 I need to use this query on Zoho analytics, it doesn't support any of these functions

Comment: @tony stark: What ConnorMcDonald is refering to is that your example with tab1.type etc. doesn't have much to do with your explanation. We'd expect a query containing a users table, a movies_watched table, a column like movie, movie_title, movie_id, whatever. The suggestion is that you update your request and change the SQL to something that clearly relates to the explanation.

Comment: @ Thorsten Kettner thanks for pointing out, I've added few pictures as reference.

Comment: Now it's movies and watchers in your explanation, cities and salesmen in your images and users and types in your example query. That only makes it worse. You are supposed to make things match in your request not the opposite.

Comment: And haven't my comments under my answer solved your issues by now, anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the opposite of a many-to-many relationship because one user maybe not watch many movies and one movie not watch by many users.

why you do retrieve it as movies not watch by the particular user.

```
select movie_name from Movie_table where movie_name not in( select movie_name from userMovieTable where user_id =: user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to join user and movie on the condition that the pair is not in the `watched` table:

```
with movies as (select distinct movie from watched)
select *
from users u
join movies m on (u.userid, m.movie) not in (select userid, movie from watched)
order by u.userid, m.movie;
```

Comment: Thanks for this. 
To add on, Zoho doesn't support **with** as well. So, I'm stuck with this. :/

Comment: Then move the query to the from clause: `join (select distinct movie from watched) m on ...`. It seems that Zoho is a bad choice., if it doesn't support basic SQL functionality. Anyway, you tagged Oracle, so you should be able to use all Oracle features. If Zoho cannot deal with that directly, then create a view in Oracle, so the features are hidden from Zoho and you simply `select * from the_view`.